# Authentication: How to configure git bash to use SAML authentication?

Tags: command-line, single-sign-on, saml, okta, github-enterprise

Single Sign On for the "GitHub Enterprise" app on Okta works fine for me, I am using SAML 2.0. When a user logs in to Okta and clicks on the "GitHub Enterprise" app, they are authenticated.

I have a "Test" repository on GitHub Enterprise. Users will use the command line or git bash to access (read/write/clone) the "Test" repo. Is there a way to use SAML authentication on the command line rather than asking for username/password or SSH key?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way for the `git` command line client to authenticate using SAML 2.0.

You will need to [suspend users in GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.7/admin/guides/user-management/suspending-and-unsuspending-users/) to disable their SSH keys.